# Securing a SPA by authorization server before first load

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using the 'new' project templates for angular SPA applications in dotnet core 2.1 as written in the article [Use the Angular project template with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio).

But this article doesn't mention anything about securing the SPA itself.
All information i find is about securing a WEBAPI but first of all i am interested in securing the SPA.

That means: When i open up my SPA e.g. https://localhost:44329/ i would like to be redirected to the authorization server *immediatly* instead of clicking some button that will do the authentication.

Background:

- I have to ensure that only a authenticated users are allowed to see the SPA.
- I want to use *Authorization Code Grant* to get refresh tokens from my authorization server.
- I cannot use *Implicit Grant* because refresh tokens cannot be kept private on the browser

**Current approach** is to enforce a MVC policy that requires a authenticated user. But this can only be applied to a MVC Controller. That's why i added *HomeController* to serve the first request.

See project structure:

[image]

My Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "CustomScheme";
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOAuth("CustomScheme", options =>
        {
            // Removed for brevity
        });

    services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
        // Require a authenticated user
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });

    // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
    });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
}
```

**Current behaviour:** When i spin up my SPA i'm immediately redirected to my authorization server because of the MVC policy. After successful authentication i see the *Index* method of the home controller but not my SPA.

So the question is how should i serve my SPA after i have been redirected from authentication server?

Comment: So, in other words, you want to control access to the html and javascript?

Comment: @john yes i think so

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm currently facing the exact same thing...

Comment: Not yet. But in the next week there should be a Solution

Comment: All right, I'll continue my research then. I'll post whatever I find here if I manage to get something

Comment: @Daniel did you figure out what had to be done? I have the same problem but it does not seem to work for me

Comment: @goldsmit409 added the current answer. I asked a Google Developer Expert about this. And what i wrote was his suggestion.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I have something that seems to work.

In my researches I stumbbled apon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503497/use-authorization-middleware-instead-of-authorizationattribute-aspnet-core/43503879#43503879) suggesting to use a middleware instead of the Authorize attribute.

Now, the method used in that post authService does not seem to work in my case (no clue why, I'll continue the investigation and post whaterver I find later on).

So I decided to go with a simpler solution. Here is my config

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                await context.ChallengeAsync("oidc");
            }
            else
            {
                await next();
            }
        });
```

In this case, oidc kicks in BEFORE the Spa app and the flow is working properly. No need for a Controller at all.

HTH

Comment: For azure also need to filter out the sign-in url to avoid endless sign-in loop - and set up CORS headers to allow browsers to work cross domain:

`app.UseCors(policy => policy.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => origin == "https://login.microsoftonline.com"));
app.UseAuthentication();
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && context.Request.Path != "/signin-oidc")
    {
        await context.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
    else
    {
        await next();
    }
});`

Comment: I've the same question but I'm using aspnet core 3.0 here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58363393/what-is-the-right-way-to-securing-a-spa-by-authorization-server-before-first-loa

Comment: This question was Authorization, not authentication. Using this method will NOT verify any of your claims and policies!

Comment: Actually this is perfect. The problem with Cirem's answer is I couldn't use it while debugging because the SPA middleware wasn't doing variable substitution/insertion in the HTML file. But this way is perfect. Just make sure this `Use` comes before `UseSPA`

Answer (score 12):

Using @George's middlware will require authentication on all requests. If you want to run this only for localhost add it under UseSpa wrapped in an env.IsDevelopment() block.

Another option that also works well for deployed environments is to return the index.html from your spa fallback route.

Startup:

```
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            builder.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "AuthorizedSpaFallBack" });
            });
        }
```

HomeController:

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult AuthorizedSpaFallBack()
{
    var file = _env.ContentRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo("ClientApp/dist/index.html");
    return PhysicalFile(file.PhysicalPath, "text/html");
}
```

If you need the base.href to match the browser request url (For example a cookie that that has a Path value) you can template that with a regex (or use a razor view like the other examples).

```
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult SpaFallback()
    {
        var fileInfo = _env.ContentRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo("ClientApp/dist/index.html");
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileInfo.CreateReadStream()))
        {
            var fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var basePath = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Url.Content("~")) ? Url.Content("~") + "/" : "/";

            //Note: basePath needs to match request path, because cookie.path is case sensitive
            fileContent = Regex.Replace(fileContent, "<base.*", $"<base href=\"{basePath}\">");
            return Content(fileContent, "text/html");
        }
    }
```

For local running and using the angular cli dev server you have to require an authenticated user before proxying (or launching the dev server in process):

```
            app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.ToString().EndsWith(".map"), appBuilder =>
                {
                    //appBuilder.UseMiddleware<RequireAuthenticationMiddleware>();
                    appBuilder.Run(async (context) =>
                    {
                        if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                        {
                            await context.ChallengeAsync();
                        }

                    });
                });
                // spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4400");
            }
        });
```

Comment: It works in production and helps me to set Base URL.Thank you

Comment: How do you initialize the _env variable ?

Comment: @Tal Inject `IHostingEnvironment` into the constructor and assign to a readonly class variable.

Comment: @George's middlware won't require authentication on all requests if you put it right above `app.UseSpa` call (after `UseMvc` / `UseEndpoit`)

Comment: Brilliant! Not sure why this seems to be such an obscure use case but this was the only answer I could find anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: Also for .NET5 use `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {                
                endpoints.MapFallbackToController(
                    "AuthorizedSpaFallBack",
                    controller: "Home");`

Comment: Is there no way to make this work while debugging? The index.html file doesn't yet exist on disk with all the path substitutions and JS insertions done by the SPA.

Comment: @PeterMoore, I updated the answer with a solution that might work for you.

Comment: Ah, I think I follow. I'll try it out thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Based on the Georges Legros I've managed to get this working for .Net Core 3 with Identity Server 4 (the out-of-the-box VS project) so that the app.UseSpa pipeline is not hit if the user is not authenticated via the identity server first. This is much nicer because you don't have to wait for the SPA to load only to then get redirected to the login.

You have to make sure you have authorization/roles working correctly or the User.Identity.IsAuthenticated will always be false.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    //Change the following pre-fab lines from

    //services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    //To

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            //You might not need the following two settings
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

    ...
}
```

Then add the following the set up the following pipe:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    //Added this to redirect to Identity Server auth prior to loading SPA    
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            await context.ChallengeAsync("Identity.Application");
        }
        else
        {
            await next();
        }
    });

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I've the same question but I'm using aspnet core 3.0 here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58363393/what-is-the-right-way-to-securing-a-spa-by-authorization-server-before-first-loa

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan my solution is for aspnet core 3.0 preview-8

Comment: @bob would you like to check my question. Maybe you can help me out

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan you're not including the Services.AddIdentity part of the solution that I've proposed above (is my guess) - you definitely need to have .AddRoles<IdentityRole>() from memory otherwise the context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated will always be false

Answer (score 3):

Make this change to your startup.cs:

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
    spa.Options.DefaultPage = "/home/index";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

Then put the reference to the angular app in the index.cshtml:

```
<app-root></app-root>
```

and make sure you include all of the needed files in the index.cshtml file or your layout:

```
<link href="~/styles.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/inline.bundle.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/polyfills.bundle.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/vendor.bundle.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/main.bundle.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

We are still working out the kinks with all of our referenced packages, but this will get the basic SPA running behind asp.net auth.

Comment: Did you ever work out how to reference the bundle.js files in a production build? The SPA seems to output them in the the format `main.[random string].bundle.js` when in production build so the static reference you have breaks.

Comment: We did, but it's not a perfect solution. You can use the environment variables to determine which versions to load e.g. : 
`<environment names="Development">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/runtime.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <script type="text/javascript" asp-src-include="~/dist/runtime.*.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>`. Be careful though, if you aren't removing older files the * will load all files matching the pattern, causing conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem today and finally got a solution, we use .NET 5 and migrated to .NET 6.
The idea was inspired by the `MapFallbackToFile` method and the above post.
Below local function `CreateRequestDelegate` is reference aspnetcore code here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Middleware/StaticFiles/src/StaticFilesEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.cs

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            //Razor pages
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            //for Web API
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            //fallback to SPA
            //endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            endpoints.MapFallback(CreateRequestDelegate(endpoints, "index.html"));
            //local function
            RequestDelegate CreateRequestDelegate(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints,string filePath)
            {
                var app = endpoints.CreateApplicationBuilder();
                //Use Cookie authentication to secure angular index.html file
                app.Use(async (context, next) =>
                {
                    bool isAuth=false;
                    //TODO: run logic to check authentication
                    //....

                    if (!isAuth)
                    {
                        await context.ChallengeAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await next.Invoke();
                    }

                });
                //to SPA index.html
                app.Use(next => context =>
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/" + filePath;
                    // Set endpoint to null so the static files middleware will handle the request.
                    context.SetEndpoint(null);
                    return next(context);
                });
                app.UseStaticFiles();
                return app.Build();
            }
            //
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no REAL solution when speaking of SPAs.

In order to execute some logic in the SPA the SPA has to be initially loaded.

But there is some kind of trick: in the `RouterModule` you can prevent the initialNavigation as shown:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'about',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'about'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { initialNavigation: false })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Then in you `app.component.ts` you can take care about your authentication:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'flight-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, private oauthService: OAuthService) {
    if (this.oauthService.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    } else {
      // login Logic
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looking at other comments there definitely are other options

Answer (score 0):

For azure ad (georges answer with karmas edit without cors):

in ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services):

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(_configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

in Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory):

```
app.UseAuthentication();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && context.Request.Path != "/signin-oidc")
    {
        await context.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
    else
    {
        await next();
    }
});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    var builder = endpoints.MapControllers();
    builder.RequireAuthorization();
});
```

Comment: When I do this, its hitting azure b2c sign in, but the app is still being rendered rather than redirecting to the MS login page >.<

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good, but they do not verify your policies, they only verify if you are authenticated.

A possible solution is to use the `IMiddelware` factory:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Tenant", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser().Requirements.Add(new TenantRequirement()));
});
```

```
app.UseMiddleware<TenantAuthorizationMiddleware>();
```

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace FieldCap.Service.Middleware
{
    public class TenantAuthorizationMiddleware : IMiddleware
    {
        private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;

        public TenantAuthorizationMiddleware(IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
        {
            _authorizationService = authorizationService;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
        {
            var result = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(context.User, "Tenant");

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/login");

                return;
            }

            await next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

This will ensure that EVERY request runs through a policy check of `tenant` too.