# What is the right way to Securing a SPA by authorization server before first load using ASP.NET Core 3.0?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using the 'new' project templates for angular v8.0 SPA applications in dotnet core 3.0 by using IDE (Visual Studio 2019).

What I'm trying to do is to securing the SPA itself before the application load first time. That means: When i open up my SPA e.g. https://localhost:44318/ i would like to be redirected to the authorization server immediately instead of clicking some button that will do the authentication.

See project structure:

[image]

What I've tried yet:

```
//Added this to redirect to Identity Server auth prior to loading SPA    
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        await context.ChallengeAsync("Identity.Application");
    }
    else
    {
        await next();
    }
});
```

above line I've added before `app.UseSpa`

My Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                await context.ChallengeAsync("Identity.Application");
            }
            else
            {
                await next();
            }
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Current behaviour:**

When I run my app I'm immediately redirected to my authorization server and routed to https://localhost:44318/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F but I'm unable to route to my SPA routes and pages. When I click on anchor link on XYZ ideally it's route on home component or if I force to route counter component from url it shows me the below same login page. Kindly help me on this what is I'm doing wrong and what is the right way to secure SPA by authorization server before first load.

**Output**

[image]

Comment: if I got your question right, you have an SPA and for a user to view the index page, they have to be authorized. Now you have implemented that but after the login button is clicked, the page still loads the auth page.

1. are you receiving the token from the server?
2. are you saving the token to locale?
3. does your app recognize the token?

Comment: When login button clicks it's authenticate my self and my email shown up but when I route my self to SPA components it doesn't allow me and take me as it is here on login page but still I'm authenticated successfully.

Answer (score 2):

you use cookie authentication, if you are not authenticated, your app redirect you to openid login page with that code.

```
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            await context.ChallengeAsync("Identity.Application");
        }
        else
        {
            await next();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Correct me if I don't see it but he's using AddIdentityServerJwt(); where do you see Cookie Authentication?