# Want to add Hybrid Flow Authentication to the (dotnet) backend of a SPA

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, react-redux, single-page-application, identityserver4

I haven't seen any documentation/examples on how to add Authentication to a SPA application, for example when using the template on ASP.NET Core 2.1 for react-redux (that uses the usual create-react-app behind the scenes).

Just to clarify, I am not asking how to add Implicit Flow authentication to the React client app, I do know how to do that, but it's not secure enough for our customers. I want the backend (ASP.NET Core) to handle authentication via an OIDC Identity Provider, using the Hybrid flow.

I am adding the following to the services pipeline:

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>;
{
    o.SlidingExpiration = bool.Parse(Configuration["SessionCookieSlidingEnabled"]);
    o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse(Configuration["SessionCookieLifeTimeInMinutes"]));
    o.Cookie = new CookieBuilder { HttpOnly = true };
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
{
    o.Authority = Configuration["Authority"];
    o.ClientId = Configuration["OpenIdConnectOptions:ClientId"];
    o.ClientSecret = Configuration["OpenIdConnectOptions:ClientSecret"];
    o.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = Convert.ToBoolean(Configuration["OpenIdConnectOptions:GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint"]);
    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = Convert.ToBoolean(Configuration["OpenIdConnectOptions:RequireHttpsMetadata"]);
    o.ResponseType = Configuration["OpenIdConnectOptions:ResponseType"];
    o.SaveTokens = Convert.ToBoolean(Configuration["OpenIdConnectOptions:SaveTokens"]);
    o.UseTokenLifetime = false;
}
```

And then the corresponding `app.UseAuthentication();` to the configure method.

Additionally, I've (unsuccessfully) tried to configure a global filter on the MVC service, like so:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                                 .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                 .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
})
```

In the past, I would simply append the [Authorize] filter to the home Controller to trigger the flow, but apparently since 2.1 the framework uses an SPA middleware to load from the ClientApp folder as the entry point for my application:

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

My question is: how do I trigger the authorization process without the controller filter?

I've already created [this inquiry](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/7644) against asp.net core docs, I know that this is not an IdentityServer4 issue, but maybe you smart folks can shed some light on the matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I see it, hybrid flow is not for spa at all.   https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/405 and https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc-example confirms that, but... would be interesting to to see something new... : )

Comment: @d_f No, I totally get that, but what I am asking is to do the Hybrid flow against the backend-server, and _then_ load the SPA after the users have successfully logged in, and have a valid cookie. Will probably use silent-refresh for the tokens afterwards.

Comment: The idea of SPA is to allow the app in the browser to work totally separately, just calling API(s) where needed, meaning no server side within the app at all. The idea of hybrid flow is to separate the browser and the server, using common clientId for both. But why not to separate the SPA and API into different oidc clients, allowing the API to use back channel (the requirement from your customer as I understand it).

Comment: That's exactly correct. In fact, the API is already a separate ApiResource (oidc client), and validates the access/reference tokens passed from the SPA against the Identity Provider server. That much is working with other web apps!

Comment: So what you actually need is to protect some static files (your spa sources) with Authorize attribute? And that's not an oidc-related question. In that aspect my first stupid idea is not to use static, just use MVC index view to load the app and perform the auth pre-check...

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought as well, and it'll get it done probably (provided I use Webpack or something else to pack my app). But what I wanted to see is if there's a way to still use the new SPA middleware from Microsoft included on Core2.1 and still perform the Authentication. I know that it is not an oidc related question, that's why I created the inquiry against MS docs for their SPA middleware / react template. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [universal solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43503879/1426685) for SPA and any other static middleware is to perform the challenge manually as the following:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                await context.ChallengeAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                await next();
            }
        });
```

This middleware should be added to the chain before Spa and Mvc.

Comment: This is perfect. I was so deep in the forest that I failed to see the simple solution. Now I can use the hybrid OIDC flow and let the asp.net middleware handle that. Thank you so much.

Comment: I've just started to use .net core 3.1 react template in the same way you proposed. Works great. My question is, how to obtain the access token in the React app? I'll need it to send requests to my api service?

Comment: @killjoy I'm not a react guru, but this [tutorial](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api#running-react) must be a kind of what you need