# Can I use Microsoft's scaffolded authorization/roles (not just authentication) for a React SPA?

Tags: reactjs, authorization, asp.net-identity, single-page-application

I'm a newbie React developer (long term ASP.NET MVC), in the early stages of our first real React SPA project (React UI on a .NET Core 3.1 Web API). I'm looking at authentication/authorization, seeing what's available.

I have scaffolded up a React SPA with authentication (i.e. login). It's... alright.

We need ~roles in the client, for some selective access to features.

There is an *authorization* (as distinct from *authentication*) system in ASP.NET Core Identity, with scaffolding and so on, which might be nice in that it's (a) done for us and (b) tested security. But all the code samples are for server-side stuff, Razor pages and MVC. Nothing for SPAs. Searching Stack Overflow I see very little about using the authorization with SPAs, and a fair number of unanswered questions.

I wonder how one would actually use this in an SPA if it's possible. I guess you would want the server login response to also give the SPA an authorization token saying "Sandra has these roles". The GUI would note that and show/hide things accordingly. Is returning roles with login results actually a thing the scaffolded Microsoft identity system can do?

Our backend already has an established authorization system it uses on normal API calls. It could expose "user A has access to features X, Z, T" as a regular data access method. However, I have been delegated to see if I can do that as part of the login, and have the scaffolding give us a GUI for creating roles and assigning users to them.

So, I guess, I'm asking: what's the sensible approach here? Do people actually use scaffolded ASP.Net roles with React apps, or do they do use third parties, or do roles as general application data outside of security, or...?

To put it another way: would you advise me to continue down this path (scaffolding Microsoft Identity to handle roles for use in a React frontend), or do something else?

Comment: did you check this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1?

Comment: Yes, for about 2 days. ;) I noted that is has a section on "Authentication with SPAs" but no corresponding section on "Authorization with SPAs".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503497/use-authorization-middleware-instead-of-authorizationattribute-aspnet-core/43503879#43503879